# ObjectInputStream's readObject() freezes after Client Socket connection is killed

Tags: java, sockets, freeze

I have following Socket server's code that reads stream from connected Socket.

```
try
{
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    int count = 10;
    while(count>0)
    {
        String msg = in.readObject().toString(); //Stucks here if this client is lost.
        System.out.println("Client Says : "+msg);
        count--;
    }
    in.close();
    client.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I have a Client program, that connects with this server, sends some string every second for 10 times, and server reads from the socket for 10 times and prints the message, but if in between I kill the Client program, the Server freezes in between instead of throwing any exception or anything.

How can I detect this freeze condition? and make this loop iterate infinitely and print whatever client sends until connection is active and stable?

Comment: the server is actually waiting for Time Out before raising any exception. You should look into the api for methods which reduce the time out value!!

Comment: @WickeD: Then it doesn't sound a good idea to change/reduce timeout value. What if connection is lost in any other way (instead of me killing the client) like getting disconnected from network, will it re-establish the connection and continue from the same state if the client gets back on the network?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the server side of the socket has no way of knowing that the client connection closed because the client code terminates without calling .close() on the client side of the socket, and therefore never sends the TCP FIN signal.

One possible way of fixing this would be to create a new Watcher thread that just periodically inspects the socket to see if it is still active. The problem with that approach is that the isConnected() on the Socket will not work for the same reason stated above so the only real way to inspect the connection is to attempt to write to it. However, this may cause random garbage to be sent to a potentially listening client.

Other options would be to implement some type of keep-alive protocol that the client should agree to (i.e., send keep-alive bits every so often so the Watcher has something to look for). You could also just move to the java.nio approach, which I believe does a better job at dealing with these conditions.

This thread is old, but provides more detail: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t541628-sockets-checking-for-dropped-connections-and-close.html.